# unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, driver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to wait until a loading image disappears off screen

If the screen is not loading the element looks like :

```
<div id="divWait" style="cursor: wait; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%; background: transparent; padding: 3px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;" xpath="1">
```

when the screen loads the element looks like:

```
   <div id="divWait" style="cursor: wait; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%; background: transparent; padding: 3px; width: 100%; height: 100%; " xpath="1">
```

the `display` disappears

The line of code i wrote for that:

```
w.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divWait\"]")), "display", "none"));
```

worth mentioning that my element is in an `iframe` but i have that handled and made sure i can parse other elements in the Iframe, i also made sure the xpath i used above is valid(copied as xpath from html)

other times i get the following exception

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: Try to use XPath to select the element without the attribute display. "div[@id='divWait' and not(@display)]" I see you've tried that, but I'm just throwing a suggestion here. If we could see the webpage it might help.

Comment: Can you write the full line of code you'd want me to try thanks.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up your two html samples. I thought when display did not exist, the page was loaded. Your code appears to target your problem correctly, but here is another sample. I honestly doubt it will make a difference. element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='divWait' and @display='none']")))

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the `divWait` div remains in the DOM at all times?  That "stale element reference" message is saying you're referring to an element that has been removed from the DOM.

Comment: @user2740650 no i cannot be sure as it mights disappear for a split second and i might not even notice from UI perspective hecking the html i can see it change but maybe that change is the divwait disappearing and then appearing again as the second loading element i shared(without the display)

Comment: For future reference, it would help to add the language you are using as a tag. It looks like you are using Java?

Comment: yes i'm using java ,sure tag added .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stale element reference error is a web driver error that occurs because the referenced web element is no longer attached to the DOM.

There are mulltiple reasons of this :

1. Element has been deleted entirely.
2. Element is no longer attached to the DOM.

Staleness occurs when a document node is removed from the DOM & its web element reference will be invalidated

**Try below code to get resolve your error :**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);              

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("divWait")));
```

**Note : please add below imports to your solution**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Comment: these imports are not getting resolved .. getting pointed as syntax errors

Comment: Syntax errors on the imports example: syntax error on token from import expected .. is that python ? and is it supposed to work in java too?

Comment: Updated solution check now

Comment: I accepted the answer because it's a valid fix of my issue, however sometimes it works and others it doesn't, for example sometimes it executes that line so fast the line after it isn't visible and i'd get this exception "no such element: Unable to locate element:" which basically sends me back to the same issue

Comment: Can you share your url ?

Comment: sadly i cannot.